# How to flatten a list of lists formed of strings?

Tags: python, string, list, data-science

I have a list formed of lists that contains strings. It looks like this:

```
["['eth', 'ethereum', 'nft', 'nonfungibletoken', 'token', 'crypto', 'digitalassets', 'etf', 'digitalcoin', 'ewallet', 'digitalgold', 'internetmoney', 'defi', 'decentralizedfinance', 'peertopeer', 'digitalcurrency', 'decentralizedmoney']",
 "['nft']",
 "['coinvotecc', 'craftnft']",
 "['coinvotecc', 'craftnft']",
 "['fitoken', 'fnk', 'nft', 'bsc', 'bnb']",
 "['nft', 'nft', 'nftarts', 'nftart', 'token', 'opeansea', 'nftcollecting', 'nftbuy', 'nfthorse', 'nftlion', 'nftold', 'nftlionesstiger', 'lion', 'lions']",
 "['nft']",]
```

I'm not sure what the '"' is for.

I'm trying to flatten it by transforming it into one big list. I've tried a lot of different ways to do so, but i'm getting errors like: 'Float objects are not iteratable' and 'str have no attribute len()'.

I'm not sure what the error is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some context ? Such as where the list comes from, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your list doesn't contain a list but a single string. So you must first convert it to a list, with `eval` being the simplest:

```py
the_list = ["['eth', 'ethereum', 'nft', 'nonfungibletoken', 'token', 'crypto', 'digitalassets', 'etf', 'digitalcoin', 'ewallet', 'digitalgold', 'internetmoney', 'defi', 'decentralizedfinance', 'peertopeer', 'digitalcurrency', 'decentralizedmoney']"]

eval(the_list[0])
```

Will give you

```py
['eth', 'ethereum', 'nft', 'nonfungibletoken', 'token', 'crypto', 'digitalassets', 'etf', 'digitalcoin', 'ewallet', 'digitalgold', 'internetmoney', 'defi', 'decentralizedfinance', 'peertopeer', 'digitalcurrency', 'decentralizedmoney']
```

Edit: If you have several strings (per your edit), you can do

```py
[eval(item) for item in the_list]
```

Edit 2: If some elements are not strings (per your subsequent comments), you could use this (and I included a way to flatten):

```py
def eval_or_keep(element):
    return eval(element) if isinstance(element, str) else [element]


list_of_lists = [eval_or_keep(item) for item in the_list]

flattened_list = [item 
                  for sub_list in list_of_lists 
                  for item in sub_list]
```

Comment: "flatten it by transforming it into one big list" you might also unpack those `eval`ed lists as an additional option.

Comment: No, my list doesnt contain a single string, but several strings.

Comment: It gives the following error: TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object.
Apparently i have non-string values. Any idea how i can filter them?

Answer (score 0):

What you have inside the big list is a couple of strings.
what you can do is just:

```
big_list = []
for s in lst:
    big_list += s[0][1:-1].split(', ')
```

it will take the strings inside the list, and will make each of them in to a list of strings, and then add them append them to a big list, such that all of the individual strings will be inside it.

Comment: My list have several strings, not a single one.

Comment: I have just edited my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in `itertools` module in Python. Using `chain.from_iterable` you can flatten all iterables within one iterable.

```
from itertools import chain 


def eval_value(value):
    # Note: if str_lst is an empty string it will give a SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
    evaluated = eval(value)
    if not isinstance(evaluated, list):
        return [evaluated]
    else:
        return evaluated

    
eval_strings = [eval_value(str_lst) for str_lst in the_list if isinstance(str_lst, str)]
flat = list(chain.from_iterable(eval_strings))
```

Comment: It gives the following error: TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: Sounds like your 'list of strings' does not just contain strings. It works on your example `the_list`

Comment: ohh i see. Any idea how i can filter the non-string values?

Comment: Are the values of NoneType or empty string/list. Then you could simply at `if str_lst` wihtin the list comprehension. Otherwise you could at `if isinstance(str_lst, str)`

Comment: so where would if isinstance(str_lst, str) fall in the code ?

Comment: I have added it to my answer

Comment: It gave this error:

TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-cdf6da2837df> in <module>
      2 
      3 str_to_lists = [eval(str_lst) for str_lst in list2 if isinstance(str_lst, str)]
      4 flat = list(chain.from_iterable(str_to_lists))

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: Can you give example code/data to reproduce this?

Comment: Sounds like your 'list strings' are sometimes numbers/floats

Comment: My original dataframe has a column which contains a list of hashtags in each row.
e.g.: ['crypto, 'nft', 'eth'], the next row might be an empty list [], and so on.
What i did is that i joined these lists into one big list. My output now is the list which is found in the post above.

The float might be due to the empty lists found.

Comment: I have created a new function `eval_value` that is a workaround for your TypeError

Comment: TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Comment: Are you sure your second argument in the isinstance() function is `str` or `list`. These shouldn't be variables, but the buildin Python type names, so you can't change these to custom names.

Comment: i didnt change it to a custom name

Comment: Can you show me your code? It works for me

Comment: from itertools import chain 


def eval_value(value):
    # Note: if str_lst is an empty string it will give a SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
    evaluated = eval(value)
    if not isinstance(evaluated, list):
        return [evaluated]
    else:
        return evaluated

    
eval_strings = [eval_value(str_lst) for str_lst in list2 if isinstance(str_lst, str)]
flat = list(chain.from_iterable(eval_strings))

Comment: Gives no error for me. Maybe you did overwrite a buildin python name. For example, you have defined a variable with the name `str` or `list`.

Comment: apparently the error is because my lists in the original dataframe are enclosed by "". I have no idea why. I guess i should remove the "" surrounding my lists. Any idea how?
Thanks a lot btw

Comment: This is what `eval()` does. It converts a string to the data within it. For example, a string containing a list will become a Python list again and a number will become a float/int